# ng Model doesn't show list of options

Tags: html, angular

Hi I have a form with a select tag, but when I use `[(ngModel)]` the list of options doesn't show.

this is my code:

```
 <select [(ngModel)]="ciudad" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" 
   <option class="placeholder" [selected] class="tagHidden" disabled>Vehículo</option>  
   <option class="placeholder" value="Quito" >Quito</option>
   <option class="placeholder" value="Guayaquil">Guayaquil</option>
   <option class="placeholder" value="Manta">Manta</option>
   <option class="placeholder" value="Portoviejo">Portoviejo</option>
   <option class="placeholder" value="Cuenca">Cuenca</option>
   <option class="placeholder" value="Machala">Machala</option>
   <option class="placeholder" value="Ibarra">Ibarra</option>
   <option class="placeholder" value="Ambato">Ambato</option>
 </select>
```

How I can resolve this issue

Comment: Can you create a working snippet?

Comment: What happens if you fix the closure of your select tag ?